# Gaussian fit fails to return the correct parameters for this PSF

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, data-fitting, astronomy

To test my 2D Gaussian fitting code for images of bright objects, I'm running it on a Point Spread Function (PSF) that was constructed and fit by the WISE team. On their website, they list the parameters for the central PSF for each band: the FWHM along the major and minor axes, and position angle (this is the angle from the y-axis). All the information is available here: [WISE PSF information](http://wise2.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/release/allsky/expsup/sec4_4c.html#rchisqind), but below is an image of those parameters for the central PSF, and the corresponding image of the PSF for band 3. 
[image: WISE PSF parameters]

[image: WISE central PSF for W3]

So, I have downloaded the corresponding FITS image for the central PSF in band 3 (all the images are available to download via the above link), and tried running my code on it. However, my code does not return the parameters I would expect, and the parameters change depending on if I fit to a subimage (and depending on the size of this), or the whole image, which is kind of worrying.

I am wondering if there's a way to make my Gaussian fit code recover the most accurate parameters -- or maybe another fitting method would be more effective. But I'm mostly concerned at the fact that the output parameters of my Gaussian fit can become so obviously wrong. Below is my code.

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

image = 'wise-w3-psf-wpro-09x09-05x05.fits' #WISE central PSF
stacked_image = fits.getdata(image)

# Center of image (the PSF is centered)
x0 = np.shape(stacked_image)[1]//2
y0 = np.shape(stacked_image)[0]//2

# Normalize image so peak = 1
def normalize(image):
    image *= 1/np.max(image)
    return image

stacked_image = normalize(stacked_image)

def gaussian_func(xy, x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta, offset):
    x, y = xy

    a = (np.cos(theta))**2/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta))**2/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -np.sin(2*theta)/(4*sigma_x**2) + np.sin(2*theta)/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta))**2/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta))**2/(2*sigma_y**2)

    inner = a * (x-x0)**2
    inner += 2*b*(x-x0)*(y-y0)
    inner += c * (y-y0)**2
    return (offset + amp * np.exp(-inner)).ravel()

def Sigma2width(sigma):
    return 2 * np.sqrt(2*np.log(2)) * sigma

def generate(data_set):
    xvec = np.arange(0, np.shape(data_set)[1], 1)
    yvec = np.arange(0, np.shape(data_set)[0], 1)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xvec, yvec)
    return X, Y


# METHOD 1: Fit subimage of PSF to Gaussian

# Guesses
theta_guess = np.deg2rad(96) #I believe that the angle in the Gaussian corresponds to CCW from the x-axis (so use WISE position angle + 90 degrees)
sigma_x = 5
sigma_y = 4
amp = 1 #I know this is true since I normalized it
subimage = stacked_image[y0-50:y0+50, x0-50:x0+50]

offset = np.min(subimage)
guesses = [np.shape(subimage)[1]//2, np.shape(subimage)[0]//2, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta_guess, offset]

xx, yy = generate(subimage)
pred_params, uncert_cov = optimize.curve_fit(gaussian_func, (xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()), subimage.ravel(), p0=guesses)
width_x, width_y = Sigma2width(np.abs(pred_params[2]))*0.275, Sigma2width(np.abs(pred_params[3]))*0.275 #multiply by pixel scale factor (available on website) to get FWHMs in arcseconds

x_0, y_0 = pred_params[0]+(x0-50), pred_params[1]+(y0-50) #add back origin
theta_deg = np.rad2deg(pred_params[5])
pred_params[5] = theta_deg
pred_params[0] = x_0
pred_params[1] = y_0

if theta_deg < 90:
    pos_angle = theta_deg+90
elif theta_deg >= 90:
    pos_angle = theta_deg-90

print('PREDICTED FWHM x, y in arcsecs:', width_x, width_y)
print('FIT PARAMS [x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta, offset]:', pred_params)
print('POSITION ANGLE:', pos_angle)

# Output: PREDICTED FWHM x, y in arcsecs: 6.4917 5.4978
# FIT PARAMS [x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta, offset]: [3.195e+02 3.189e+02 1.002e+01 8.489e+00 8.695e-01 8.655e+01 2.613e-02]
# POSITION ANGLE: 176.556


# METHOD 2: Fit whole image to Gaussian

# Guesses
theta_guess = np.deg2rad(96)
sigma_x = 5
sigma_y = 4
amp = 1
offset = np.median(stacked_image)
guesses = [x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta_guess, offset]

# Sigmas - manual estimation
ylim, xlim = np.shape(stacked_image)
x, y = np.arange(0, xlim, 1), np.arange(0, ylim, 1)
ypix, xpix = np.where(stacked_image==amp)

y_range = np.take(stacked_image, ypix[0], axis=0)
x_range = np.take(stacked_image, xpix[0], axis=1)

xx, yy = generate(stacked_image)
pred_params, uncert_cov = optimize.curve_fit(gaussian_func, (xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()), stacked_image.ravel(), p0=guesses)
width_x, width_y = Sigma2width(np.abs(pred_params[2]))*0.275, Sigma2width(np.abs(pred_params[3]))*0.275 #in arcsecs
theta = pred_params[5]

print('PREDICTED FWHM x, y in arcsecs:', width_x, width_y)
print('FIT PARAMS [x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta, offset]:', pred_params)

# Output: 
# PREDICTED FWHM x, y in arcsecs: 7.088 6.106
# FIT PARAMS [x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, amp, theta, offset]: [3.195e+02 3.190e+02 1.095e+01 9.429e+00 8.378e-01 1.521e+00 7.998e-04]

if theta < 90:
    pos_angle = 90+np.rad2deg(theta)
elif theta >= 90:
    pos_angle = 90-np.rad2deg(theta)

print('POSITION ANGLE:', pos_angle)

# POSITION ANGLE: 177.147
```

You can see in the (rounded) outputs that the amplitudes my Gaussian fits return aren't even 1, and the other parameters (FWHMs and angles) don't match up with the correct parameters shown in the table either.

If I fit a subimage, it seems that the amplitude gets closer and closer to (but never reaches) 1 the smaller I make the subimage, but then the FWHMs might get too small compared to the real values. Why am I not getting back the correct results, and how can I make the fit as accurate as possible?

Comment: There seems to be a fourfold ray-structure. Does this image have artifacts due to blend components. Then a Gaussian should not work anyway, right?

Comment: @mikuszefski I'm not too sure what you mean, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: While the color scale might not be the most appropriate, I can see that this dot is not a Gaussian. (Like Fig 8 on the page you linked ).

Comment: Well, Figure 8 on the page simply shows the profiles through the semi-major and minor axes of this image. Are you saying that does not look Gaussian either? For my purposes, it doesn't need to be a perfect Gaussian -- I'd just like to use a Gaussian fit to determine the FWHMs, amplitude, etc., which I thought the fit would still be able to find accurately.

Comment: Sorry I meant 8a. Anyhow, I was wondering, just opening the PSF images in GIMP and changing the levels shows me that this is quite deformed. Moreover, (with the little time I had to look over the page) I don't see on this WISE page where they say this can be fitted by a Gaussian. I only see that they assume Gaussian noise. `H()` is not really written explicitly and I have the feeling it is heuristic,i.e. a system property they get. This web page is quite hard to read if you are not deep into this astronomy topic. Can you contact one of the scientist responsible for this "mess"?

Comment: Well all I really would like to do is have an accurate way to find the FWHMs of this image in Python along different directions -- perhaps I should abandon the Gaussian fit method. I did try a different method involving simply measuring the FWHMs using the roots of `UnivariateSpline`, but oddly it returns smaller widths for the semi-major and minor axes than what is documented on the webpage.

Comment: ...brings me back to my first question. Why a Gaussian in the first place? Where on the web page can I find the information that they fitted this profile with a Gaussian?

Comment: Generally, a PSF is assumed to be a Gaussian (that doesn't mean it's a perfect Gaussian, though). This assumption is also often used as an example with the astropy `photutils.psf` package.

Comment: ok. so back to square 1, checking your Gaussian fit (BTW I'd rather rotate x and y to x' y' then fiddling with the sigmas or put a full matrix description,i.e. covariance matrix)